# How to achieve custom line breaking of URLs in a 'framed' environment?

Tags: line-breaking, urls, framed

I have a long line, which could be a url but is not always a url so I cant use url/burl package. I want to specify where to break (at `&`), and how to do it.

Long line:

```
long-example-url.com/foo.php?foofighter=bar&session=89c371a38aa60a9a59f46c9bbdc9fb2d&fun=yes
```

not long line:

```
long-example-url.com/foo.php?foofighter=bar      &session=89c371a38aa60a9a59f46c9bbdc9fb2d&fun=yes
```

insert a `\` at the end of the line and indent at the next to indicate the break.

How do I do this? (the text is inside a framed and is using `verbatim` environment)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
  \begin{verbatim}
    Example:

    long-example-url.com/foo.php?foofighter=bar&session=89c371a38aa60a9a59f46c9bbdc9fb2d&fun=yes
  \end{verbatim}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a
greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange
at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of
our trying to keep everything very concise.
[Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)
is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Please always try to supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) we can play with.

Comment: `verbatim` doesn't allow line breaks: it's supposed not to, since it's for *reproducing* code listings.

Answer (score 1):

I put the following line in my Praeamble on top of using the url-package:

```
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\+}
```

after each \do, you can specify one sign, where the url shall break.

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Reconsidering my answer one more time. You can use the `listings` package for this, but it can break before AND after the characters from the group `other`. So it will be broken off after the `&` sign, not before.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} % coloring only

\begin{document}

\newcommand\brch{\textbackslash}

\lstset{%
    alsoletter={0123456789=},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines,
    breakautoindent=true,
    breakindent=20pt,
    prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\color{green}\textbackslash},
}

\begin{lstlisting}
long-example-url.com/foo.php?foofighter=bar&session=89c371a38aa60a9a59f46c9bbdc9fb2d&fun=yes
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The only painful stuff is to specify the `alsoletter` option. I've just asked [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140595/can-i-get-the-list-of-all-letter-digit-other-characters-inside-latex) about the automatization of that.