# Can I get the list of all letter/digit/other characters inside LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, listings

I'm searching for a command which is (almost) the inverse of `\catcode`. Is there a command to print all the characters of a character group?

Use-case: disable linebreaking of listings at all but one character of the "other" group using the `alsoletter` option. Something like this.

```
\lstset{alsoletter={\charother{}}}
```

I would like to drop one character from the list using `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package.

Comment: Hello! This is not obviously what you really need, you want to list some file. Show us what is your true intention and it'll be much easier to help you ;)  See also [XY Problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean)

Comment: @tohecz: I want to list text (without the need of escaping) broken apart only at `&` characters.